# Insert timestamp based on specific criteria

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I'm trying to create a basic timestamp script. In short, I run some tasks that go through different statuses (status 1, 2, 3, etc). I want to track the timestamp of each status per task (row).

I already have a code that can do so, but only when I manually input the status one by one in the first column (timestamps are properly added in their respective status column), but I can't update multiple at a time.

If I paste multiple 'status', the script only runs the timestamp based on the first row, and doesn't respect the other status. Here's a very short [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IkbtP9u0PJOpi8UAV80rXK9wnI0m4jo5/view?usp=sharing) that demonstrates what it's doing.

I'll be using the script in a big file that automatically gets updated, but I can't get it to work. Here's the code that I'm currently using (apologize if it's something simple, I'm amateur at best).

```
function OnEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var rows = range.getNumRows();
  var date = new Date();
  var dates = sheet

      .getRange(row, 3, rows)
      .getValues()
      .map(function(row) {return [row[0] || date];});
if(sheet.getRange(row, 1,rows).getValue()==1) {   sheet
   .getRange(row, 2, rows)
   .setValues(dates);
  }
  else
  {if(sheet.getRange(row, 1,rows).getValue()==2) {   sheet
   .getRange(row, 3, rows)
   .setValues(dates);
  }
    else
  {if(sheet.getRange(row, 1,rows).getValue()==3) {   sheet
   .getRange(row, 4, rows)
   .setValues(dates);
                                                 }
  }
  }
}
```

If status=1, insert timestamp in 'Col B', if status=2, insert timestamp in 'Col C' and so on.

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14xujKhSgnlBnA0o84UkArRfBP1GVwYOTDQQynaWQm34/edit#gid=0)'s the sheet where I'm working.

Comment: This doesn't make sense `if(sheet.getRange(row, 1,rows).getValue()==1)` if `rows >1` You will just get the upper left cell value.

Comment: I believe that's the column, if the row in column 1 = 1, insert timestamp in column 2. and so on. Feel free to try it out: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14xujKhSgnlBnA0o84UkArRfBP1GVwYOTDQQynaWQm34/edit#gid=0

The problem for me however, is doing multiple at a time (when pasting multiple status).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

So now you can edit either one cell or many cells as in a copy and paste in column1 and the timestamps will appear in the columns `e.range.columnStart + whatever the selection in column one was`. I used a data validation on column one but you can do whatever you wish. You'll probably want to add a conditional like `if(e.range.getSheet().getName()!='Sheet1'){return;}`

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var timeStamp=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "E MMM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  if(e.range.columnStart==1 && e.range.rowStart>1) {//if you are editing column1
    var sA=e.range.getValues();//get all values in range
    for(var i=0;i<sA.length;i++) {
      e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart+i,Number(sA[i][0]) + e.range.columnStart).setValue(timeStamp);
    }
  }
}
```

This is what my sheet lookslike:

[image]

I added some choices to the valid for more timestamp columns

Alternative Solution with additional requirements:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var timeStamp=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "E MMM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  if(e.range.columnStart==1 && e.range.rowStart>1) {//if you are editing column1
    var sA=e.range.getValues();//get all values in range
    for(var i=0;i<sA.length;i++) {
      var ts=e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart+i,Number(sA[i][0]) + e.range.columnStart).getValue();
      if(sA[i][0]>0 && !ts) {
        e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart+i,Number(sA[i][0]) + e.range.columnStart).setValue(timeStamp);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this one selects column by column header name so that you can add columns to left of column1. It also restricts action to a specific sheet in this case Sheet92.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName()!='Sheet92'){return;}
  var colName=e.range.getSheet().getRange(1,e.range.columnStart).getValue();
  var timeStamp=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "E MMM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  if(colName=='Status Choice' && e.range.rowStart>1) {
    var sA=e.range.getValues();
    for(var i=0;i<sA.length;i++) {
      var ts=e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart+i,Number(sA[i][0]) + e.range.columnStart).getValue();
      if(sA[i][0]>0 && !ts) {
        e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart+i,Number(sA[i][0]) + e.range.columnStart).setValue(timeStamp);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Make sure that you get the last version as I've edited it a couple of times.

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic, Cooper! If it's not too much hassle, is there a way to check the timestamp column to only insert a timestamp if it's blank? (to avoid overwriting an existing timestamp?)

Also, I noticed that if the 'Status Choice' cell gets deleted (0 or null), it inserts a timestamp instead of the status (the first column). Is there a way to limit the timestamp to only be inserted in the specific timestamp ranges (ex, B:G). Appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks for the updates Cooper, I would've never be able to come up with this. FInal question, I'm trying to leave formulas in the Status Choice column, example on column A, row 2 (the first status): `if(Z2="Status1",1,if(Z2="Status2",2,"")`but the timestamp doesn't trigger with formula results. Would you happen to know why, or how can I make it work with formulas?  (so that I fill all column 1 with formulas to read the actual row text status, and return a number (1-10) to add the respective timestamp. (I have another script that constantly inserts the actual text status) Again, thanks.

Comment: Simple triggers are designed to run only when a user makes a change. There are some installable triggers that detect some changes.  You can read about them [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#google_apps_triggers).

Comment: I would say that your best option is to use data validation in that column